# Calculate within a buffer around a point the % of area covered per category

Tags: qgis, area

I have to calculate within a buffer of 10 m around each sensor (and later 50 m, 100 m, 100 m...) **how much % of the area in that buffer is covered by each Landscape Element (LE)**. The goal? An attribute table (and later CSV file) which looks kind of like this:

[image: The goal]

For this, I have a vector file with different sensor locations, and a vector file made from a raster file which contains information on the presence of different landscape elements (LE) in the region (dark green = LE 1 = high vegetation; light green = LE 2 = low vegetation; yellow = LE 3 = agriculture; grey = LE 4 = build-up area; blue = LE 5 = water). The result is a map which looks like the one below:

[image: sensor location and landscape surrounding it.]

How should I proceed getting this area information (I think using the field calculator) and how do I couple this area information to each sensor?

A link to a wetransfer with the QGIS files: https://we.tl/t-yEDN800iEJ

Comment: So, you want to `vectorize` the rasterdata with burned in LE-categories, then `intersect` the data with the buffers and finally use the field calculator to calculate the percentages. Where are you stuck on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the raster you can use zonal histogram and field calculator. My raster have three classes 0, 1 and 2.

After zonal histogram I Field calculate the first percentage as:

```
("HISTO_0"/("HISTO_0"+"HISTO_1"+"HISTO_2"))*100
```

[image]